# How do I inject binary files into a v1.7 pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have a 3rd party docker image that I want to use (https://github.com/coreos/dex/releases/tag/v2.10.0). I need to inject some customisation into the pod (CSS stylesheet and PNG images).

I haven't found a suitable way to do this yet. Configmap binaryData is not available before v1.10 (or 9, can't remember off the top of my head). I could create a new image and `COPY` the PNG files into the image, but I don't want the overhead of maintaining this new image - far safer to just use the provided image.

Is there an easy way of injecting these 2/3 files I need into the pod I create?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to mount 1 or more volumes into the desired locations within the pod, seemingly `/web/static`. This however would overwrite the entire directly so you would need to supply all the files not just those you wish to overwrite.

Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: dex:2.10.0
    name: dex
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /web/static # the mount location within the container
      name: dex-volume
  volumes:
  - name: dex-volume
    hostPath:
      path: /destination/on/K8s/node # path on host machine
```

There are a number of types of storage types for different cloud providers so take a look at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/ and see if theres something a little more specific to your environment rather than storing on disk.

For what it's worth, creating your own image would probably be the simplest solution.

Comment: can you give an example or link on how to do that. I looked, thinking I could mount a container image onto a path but couldn't find anything obvious to me.  Overwriting the entire directory is fine

Answer (score 0):

You could mount your custom files into a volume, and additionally define a set of commands to run on pod startup (see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/)) to copy your files to their target path.

You of course need to also run the command that starts your service, in addition to the ones that copy your files.